# ¿Como hacer mi script se haga en bucle?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

he creado el siguiente script:

```
$(".circulo").click(function() {
  $('form').show();
});


$("#next").click(function() {
  $("#test1").hide();
  $("#test2").show();
});

$("#back").click(function() {
  $("#test1").show();
  $("#test2").hide();
});
```

para el siguiente form:

Lo que pasa aqui es hay un formulario que esta en `display:none`, cuando le das a circulo este se deja ver, luego el formulario esta dividido en dos partes la primera te muestra dos inputs, cuando le das a next te pone el primer grupo en hide y el segundo en show, y en el segundo hay uno que te deja volver hacia atras. El tema es que solo funciona una vez, luego ya no mas. Y ademas tengo que implementar en el script una funcion, que cuado hagas submit, ponga todo el form en hide, y no se muy bien si usar  `window.close();`.
Alguien me puede hechar una mano?

P.D: El código funcional esta [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/Saggi/qom01zxt/)

Comment: A que te referís cuando decir "...solo funciona una vez"? yo lo probé y funciona todo según tu descripción. Ahora, para ocultar el form, puedes usar $('form').hide(); y luego hacer el submit desd js.

Comment: Probe el codigo y todo funciona bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no sé si sirva de algo pero..., si al boton en lugar de hacer submit haces esto

```
<div class="body">
   <div class="circulo">
   </div>
   <div id='head'>
      <form name="mi_formulario" method="post">
         <div id="test1">
            <div>
               <label for="avatar">Profile picture:</label>
               <input type="file"
                  id="avatar" name="avatar"
                  accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="msg">Message:</label>
               <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
               <div id="next">
                  next
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
         <div id="test2">
            <div>
               <label for="name">Name:</label>
               <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
            </div>
            <div>
               <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
               <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
            </div>
            <div class="button">
               <button id="submit_button" onclick="send_form();">Send your message</button>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
               <div id="back">
                  back
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

lo que he heco es ponerle nombre al formulario y quitar el tipe submit al boton y agregarle un funcion javascript que es la siguiente.

```
function send_form(){
    document.forms.mi_formulario.submit();
    $('form').hide();
}
```

es lo que se me ocurre ahora mismo, seguro que se puede hacer más simple pero bueno, espero que esto te ayude. 
Un saludo.